how to spawn objects in a random Vector3 position that has not been occupied?
I am trying to spawn game objects randomly in unoccupied positions on my game board.
The steps I plan to take to achieve this are:

Create an array of Vector3 containing the coordinates of all available positions
Using Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation), call Random.Range on the index of the array to spawn randomly
Create a boolean to check if the position at an index is still available

    Vector3[] randomPos = new Vector3[9];
    Vector3 randomPos[0] = new Vector3(-2.5, 3.6, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[1] = new Vector3(0, 3.6, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[2] = new Vector3(2.5, 3.6, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[3] = new Vector3(-2.5, 1, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[4] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[5] = new Vector3(2.5, 1, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[6] = new Vector3(-2.5, -1.6, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[7] = new Vector3(0, -1.6, 0);
    Vector3 randomPos[8] = new Vector3(2.5, -1.6, 0);

My code in step 1 is resulting in the errors below:

Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.

Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)


How do i fix it?
To fix error 1, I tried
    Vector3[0] randomPos = new Vector3(-2.5, 3.6, 0);
    Vector3[1] randomPos = new Vector3(0, 3.6, 0);
    Vector3[2] randomPos = new Vector3(2.5, 3.6, 0);
    Vector3[3] randomPos = new Vector3(-2.5, 1, 0);
    Vector3[4] randomPos = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    Vector3[5] randomPos = new Vector3(2.5, 1, 0);
    Vector3[6] randomPos = new Vector3(-2.5, -1.6, 0);
    Vector3[7] randomPos = new Vector3(0, -1.6, 0);
    Vector3[8] randomPos = new Vector3(2.5, -1.6, 0);


based on suggestions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/array-declaration-errors#invalid-array-rank.
Error 1 changed to The type 'GameScript' already contains a definition for 'randomPos'...
For error 2, I dont understand the issue since I had already used the new keyword? Thank you very much

It is basic syntax error. In C#, when you declare and initialize an array, you don't use the array index syntax (randomPos[0], randomPos[1], etc.) again when assigning values to individual elements. Fixed code:
Vector3[] randomPos = new Vector3[9];
randomPos[0] = new Vector3(-2.5, 3.6, 0);
randomPos[1] = new Vector3(0, 3.6, 0);
randomPos[2] = new Vector3(2.5, 3.6, 0);
randomPos[3] = new Vector3(-2.5, 1, 0);
randomPos[4] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
randomPos[5] = new Vector3(2.5, 1, 0);
randomPos[6] = new Vector3(-2.5, -1.6, 0);
randomPos[7] = new Vector3(0, -1.6, 0);
randomPos[8] = new Vector3(2.5, -1.6, 0);


Yeahh, I tried this initially too... But I changed it cuzz this gives me another set of errors:

Type expected
Syntax error, ',' expected
Identifier expected
Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Any ideas what went wrong?


Can you post the whole script and error?

thank you, but i deleted this code cuzz i found another solution to spawn randomly without the Vector 3... it is probably something else in my script that caused those errors...
